# How to Crawl the metadata for pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, properties, crawl

I need to crawl the data of `fileRef`. How to handle to proceed with that? This information is contained inside the pages. Can anyone assist with this?

```
{
    "odata.type": "SP.Data.PagesItem",
    "odata.id": "Web/Lists(guid'e742e0aa-ff77-42b2-9660-6aaa975e03ab')/Items(6)",
    "odata.etag": "\"35\"",
    "odata.editLink": "Web/Lists(guid'e742e0aa-ff77-42b2-9660-6aaa975e03ab')/Items(6)",
    "Id": 6,
    "Title": null,
    "ID": 6,
    "FileRef": "/sites/pnp/Pages/atozindex.aspx"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the content is be regarded as the content in the page, then it will be crawled in the page.

If the content is in one web part in the page, then the content will not be crawled.

And in SharePoint online environment, the crawl will run automatically.

Comment: The fileRef will redirect the pages contains list of documents like a,b,c upto Z. 
Need to crawl those metadata only even though no need content of the document.

https://www.sitename.com/Pages/atozindex.aspx


For example :


A - Administration

application Development
 
 
 
B

Benifits of employement
Backup documents


upto z Pages